# Exception on renaming GitHub speech to text recognition using Google API project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, speech-recognition

I am a novice to C# i'm not sure if I'm writing on the right forum for this question . I just downloaded speech recognition using Google Api winForms project from GitHub. Initially its was this exception

> NuGet Package restore failed for project WinRecognize: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters..

So, I renamed the project folder, exception disappeared, but now I am getting following exceptions while in debugging mode after pressing "voice detect" button in output

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Google.Api.Gax.dll Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Google.Api.Gax.dll Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Google.Api.Gax.dll Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Google.Api.Gax.dll

Comment: checkout the code in root of the drive D:\WinRecognize to have shorter folders. [In VS exception options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger#add-and-delete-exceptions) activate the System.InvalidOperationException now debugger stops at the point were the issue occurs.

Comment: any update on your issue?